# Disable button with jQuery while still firing server-side event

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, onload

I know similar questions have been posted before, but I haven't seen one with some of the requirements below.

In my markup, I have a div that contains an input field and an ASP.NET button. 
The button has a server-side OnClick event handler that does some misc. work.

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="contactForm">
    <input type="text" id="email" runat="server" class="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" />  
    <asp:Button ID="plhButton" class="submit-btn" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Request Information" />
</div>
```

and the event handler:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       EmailPost();
       //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

I also would like the following:

- Disable the button for 4 seconds
- Change the button text while disabled
- Revert the button text after it's re-enabled
- Check for validation

This is my script to handle that:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var fewSeconds = 4;
    $(".submit-btn").click(function () {
        if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.prop('disabled', true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                btn.prop('disabled', false);
                btn.prop('value', 'Request Information');
            }, fewSeconds * 1000);

            btn.prop('value', 'Sending...');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

It all works fine, except that disabling the button prevents my server-side event from firing. 
So, I've added UseSubmitBehavior="false" to my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="plhButton" class="submit-btn" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Request Information" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Now, the server-side event fires normally, but the code inside the script (i.e., disabling the button, toggling the button text) only runs the first time the button is clicked..

Any ideas how to make the script code run more that once?

Comment: Aren't you submitting a form so JavaScript code is useless since as soon as the page is submitted all that code stops running.

Comment: @epascarello Good point! I've replaced `$(document).ready` with function `pageLoad()` and it seems to be working now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

@epascarello pointed me in the right direction; I switched `$(document).ready` with `function pageLoad()` and that did it:

```
<script>
    function pageLoad(){
        var fewSeconds = 4;
        $(".submit-btn").click(function () {
            if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                var btn = $(this);
                btn.prop('disabled', true);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    btn.prop('disabled', false);
                    btn.prop('value', 'Hmm.. Try again');
                }, fewSeconds * 1000);

                btn.prop('value', 'Sending...');
            }
        });

    };
</script>
```